# how to change caml query with condition <OR> for 5000+ list items

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, caml

I have this CAML query that wouldn't work if i change it to  but works with  HOWEVER. since our list no has 15k items using OR doesnt work. basically this remote event receiver gets list items with this CAML Query:

```
 var query = string.Format(
                @"<View>
                    <Query>
                       <Where>
                          <And>
                              <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name='IsCurrentBooking' />
                                <Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value>
                              </Eq>
                              <And>
                                  <And>
                                     <Or>
                                        <Eq>
                                           <FieldRef Name='NG_BookingStatus' />
                                           <Value Type='Choice'>{2}</Value>
                                        </Eq>
                                        <Eq>
                                           <FieldRef Name='NG_BookingStatus' />
                                           <Value Type='Choice'>{3}</Value>
                                        </Eq>
                                     </Or>
                                     <And>
                                        <Lt>
                                            <FieldRef Name='NG_EventDate' />
                                            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime' StorageTZ='TRUE'>{1}</Value>
                                        </Lt>
                                        <Gt>
                                            <FieldRef Name='NG_EndDate' />
                                            <Value IncludeTimeValue='TRUE' Type='DateTime' StorageTZ='TRUE'>{0}</Value>
                                        </Gt>
                                    </And>
                                  </And>
                                  <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name='NG_Venues' LookupId='TRUE' />
                                    <Value Type='LookupMulti'>{4}</Value>
                                  </Eq>
                              </And>
                           </And>
                       </Where>
                        <OrderBy>
                            <FieldRef Name='NG_EventDate' Ascending='True' />
                        </OrderBy>
                    </Query>
                </View>"
                , startDate, endDate, status_w1, status_w2, venueId);
```

this condition in particular:

```
<Or>
   <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='NG_BookingStatus' />
      <Value Type='Choice'>{2}</Value>
    </Eq>
    <Eq>
       <FieldRef Name='NG_BookingStatus' />
       <Value Type='Choice'>{3}</Value>
     </Eq>
</Or>
```

I've [read here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1076854/Overcoming-the-List-View-Threshold-in-SharePoint-C) never to use OR but i am not sure what to do because changing it to AND does not return any time for obvious reasons. but i cant seem to get how to workaround this.

Answer (score 0):

The article you reference gives the only answer you're going to get:

> Your only option here is to run multiple queries.

So do one query with AND:

```
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='NG_BookingStatus' />
    <Value Type='Choice'>{2}</Value>
</Eq>
```

and another query with AND:

```
<Eq>
    <FieldRef Name='NG_BookingStatus' />
    <Value Type='Choice'>{3}</Value>
</Eq>
```

and manually merge the results.